# fso.deletefolder DeletePathPath not found

Tags: ms-access, fso

I use this statement in a Loop to delete a bunch of folders at a time.
fso.deletefolder DeletePath, True

Prior to the above statement I do this to make sure it actually exist.
If fso.FolderExists(DeletePath) = False Then

However, occassionaly get a Path Not Found error when it hits the delete statement. When I check the folder is there and I can delete it manually. Today my code sucessfully deleted 17 folders and failed on 2.

For my FolderExists logic I update the table I am reading with a Missing comment. I would like to do the same with the Delete. If "failed" then update the table with "Failed" and keep processing. Need help on this If statement.

Thanks.

Comment: Edit question to provide code.

Comment: also provide an example filename that fails.  i"m wondering if it is a file with spaces in the filename.

Comment: All the paths include at least one space. 1 of 8 failed today so and the 7 that succeeded had a space.